# Regular prism tangent to a sphere

Tags: geometry, 3d

A straight, hexagonal, regular prism has its 18 edges tangent to a sphere of radius r. To determine: a) The fraction of the sphere area that is located outside the side faces of the prism. b) The fraction of the volume of the same sphere that is found outside the bases of the prism. NOTE: The sphere is neither inscribed nor circumscribed to the prism; the 8 faces of the prism section the sphere

Can someone draw this situation for me?  I couldn't imagine this figure. Thanks for attention.

Comment: Note that the hexagonal prism tangent points create an inscribed hexagon at the sphere center. At the vertical direction they create 6 inscribed squares. The hexagonal prism edges equals the sphere radius.

Comment: Here's a picture: https://www.geogebra.org/classic/ybk4ync9

Comment: @aretino Very nice figure. I wouldn't have imagined that it was possible with Geogebra to hhave these kind of transparence effect. As it is the objective of the OP, you should give it as a (partial) answer : I would upvote it immediately...

Comment: Very nice Aretino - exactly as described in my comment.

Comment: @Cavalo: Are you still looking for a solution? Using the nice figure posted in the comments the calculations are straightforward.